# Data table subset using a condition, and only specific rows from that subset

Tags: r, data.table, subset

I have a big data table that is rendered in a plotly plot, and the user can select points in the scatter plot with a region (rectangular or polygon). After processing this select element, I get a dataframe with a list of the 'cluster' each point in the selection belongs to and which 'nth' element (row) of that cluster it is, i.e.

```
cluster    elementNr    
1             1    
1             23    
2             7
2             9
2             14
```

This recreates the output:

```
selectme <- data.frame(cluster = c(rep(1,20), rep(2,30)), elementNr = c(sample(1:100, 20, replace = F),sample(1:100,30, replace =F)))
```

And this creates the dummy equivalent of my main data table

```
mydata <- data.table(cluster = sample(c(1:5), 5000, replace = T), val1 = runif(5000, 0.1, 100), val2 = runif(5000, 0.1, 50))
```

What I am trying to figure out, is how to subset the data table with the selectme dataframe so that I get the right particles out of there. 
i.e. as the first example, I should end up with the 1st and 23rd row of the rows where cluster == 1, and the 7th, 9th, 14th row of those where cluster == 2

Expected output:

```
Cluster   val1    val2
 1        0.45    2.54     (1st of this cluster 
 1        25.73   84.83  (23rd element of this cluster 
 2        0.26    12.76   (7th el)
 2        3.16    26.84   (9th el)
 2        0.76    19.46   (14th el)
```

- values are just examples since the test code creates them at random

So 7th element is not the 7th row of mydata, but the 7th row of the subset where cluster ==2
 And because my data can contain dozens of clusters I would like to put the following logical sentence into code: 
"For each cluster in selectme, find the rows of the subset of mydata where cluster equals the same cluster and grab the rows that equal the elementnrs of selectme  for the current cluster, and produce one output containing all the corresponding rows"

I can transfer myselection to data.table first if needed of course

**UPDATE: real data added**

Real data file, real selectme file, and expected output file in RDS form are found here: 
[datafiles](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jhTN2b9-UOXqpfGOs6qCdpwiyVPzF6vn?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you provide an example that shows the structure of your expected output?

Comment: See edit Dan hall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the data you provided:

```
mydata <- data.table(cluster = sample(c(1:5), 5000, replace = T), 
                     val1 = runif(5000, 0.1, 100), 
                     val2 = runif(5000, 0.1, 50))

selectme <- data.frame(cluster = c(rep(1,20), rep(2,30)), 
                       elementNr = c(sample(1:100, 20, replace = F),
                       sample(1:100,30, replace =F)))

# One at a time:
mydata[cluster == 1][selectme[selectme$cluster == 1,]$elementNr]
#    cluster       val1      val2
# 1:       1 92.7082853 34.879758
# 2:       1  6.2921762 19.203557
# 3:       1 32.5258127  3.731329
# 4:       1 93.5793112 34.937362
# 5:       1 62.0401740 42.491657
# and so on...

# Programmatically

clusters <- unique(selectme$cluster)
tobind <- vector("list", length(clusters))
for (i in seq_along(tobind)){
  tobind[[i]] <- mydata[cluster == clusters[i]][selectme[selectme$cluster == clusters[i],]$elementNr]
}

selected <- rbindlist(tobind)
```

Comment: 2 questions: how come you get 2 identical rows in your outputs and second , is there no way to do it in one go? My code runs in a shiny app and needs to automatically take care of whatever nr of clusters the data has at the moment of execution

Comment: The latter could be achieved by something like lapply to unique(selectme$cluster) I suppose but I hope there is another way without loop

Comment: That would be programmatically putting it together based on your constraints, which I don't know. I gave you an example. I hope you find it helpful! There are many ways to do it. The reason the lines are the same is because that's what your example provides. You can run the parts and examine them, for example: `selectme[selectme$cluster == 1,]$elementNr` repeats, so `mydata[selectme[selectme$cluster == 1,]$elementNr]` will to, as will the final output.

Comment: If you found the work I did on your project helpful, please upvote. If it answered the question you posed, please select it as the answer. If you have additional questions and you want to ask them, please write another question and I'll see if I can help you!

Comment: An example of an additional question you could ask (in another question): your clusters have repeated values (do they in your actual data?), how do you subset your datatable so that the rows are unique?  If I helped you here with this answer, then you can ask that additional question and I'll help you there.

Comment: My mistake in the dummy data generation. Myselection  was supposed to have only unique values within one cluster, but possible duplicates overall. Code should be correct now

Comment: Other than that your bind edit should do it. Will test it as soon as I'm in my office and accept the answer if it works for me.

Comment: Your code (maybe due to my mistake in test data) gave 4 rows of output with the new selectmen, while mydata[mydata$cluster ==1, ] was 1054 rows and myselect[my selects cluster==1,] is 20 rows. So it should give 20 rows as result.   This actually works: mydata[mydata$cluster == 1][selectme[selectme$cluster== 1,]$elementNr,]

Comment: That won't give you the correct rows, though, since elementNr is the row number in the original data table.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166453/discussion-between-dan-hall-and-mark).

Answer (score 0):

After creating an index for each row, you can do an inner join using the data.table as follows

```
set.seed(8L)
selectme <- data.table(cluster = c(rep(1L,20), rep(2L,30)), elementNr = c(sample(1:100, 20, replace = F),sample(1:100,30, replace =F)))
mydata <- data.table(cluster = sample(c(1:5), 5000, replace = T), val1 = runif(5000, 0.1, 100), val2 = runif(5000, 0.1, 50))

selectme[mydata[, rn := .I, by=.(cluster)],
    on=c("cluster", "elementNr"="rn"), nomatch=0L]
```

Comment: chinsoon, this gives me a result of only 8 rows I just found out, whereas selectme has 50 rows to find in mydata, so this is not working as intended it seems

Comment: What seed did you use?

Comment: i tried both set.seed(8L) and (50L), result is the same

Comment: > set.seed(50L)
> 
> selectme[mydata[, rn := .I, by=.(cluster)],
+          on=c("cluster", "elementNr"="rn"), nomatch=0L]
   cluster elementNr       val1      val2
1:       2         8 45.8819275 33.209936
2:       2        20  1.5607475 38.165564
3:       2        33 14.4914165 31.441877
4:       2        37 18.6051432 30.325859
5:       2        38 28.2349863  7.467059
6:       2        53 92.6759431 14.885305
7:       1        75 87.6306055 41.400328
8:       2        96  0.5877996 21.057264

Comment: In your original post, what seed did you use? I was unable to replicate your dataset.

Comment: I don't think I actually set a seed conciously. If there was a seed set, it was  set.seed(42) from a previous part of code I ran in my shiny app, but the data is random numbers. The exact values don't matter. What matters is that the number of rows in both tables is fixed, 5000 and 50, and the solution should thus find 50 rows like Dan's code does

Comment: Just fix your dataset and run the code. Otherwise the output will never tie because the inputs are random

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166523/discussion-between-mark-and-chinsoon12).

Comment: Not next to a computer now. Just use a real dataset without any randomness, then show what you want. If it’s still wrong then I will fix it